# Are there JavaScript equivalents of the Vim regular expression start and end of word atoms "\<" and "\>"?

Tags: javascript, regex, vim, word-boundary, word-boundaries

I know most regular expression engines, including the one in JavaScript have `\b` to match a word boundary, be it at either the start or end of a word.

But Vim also has two more specific regular expression atoms:

- [`\<` matches only the word boundary at the start of a word](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%3C)
- [`\>` matches only the word boundary at the end of a word](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%3E)

Does JavaScript have an equivalent to these atoms, and if not is there a way to express their more precise semantics some other way?

Comment: Actually I just started to worry that `\<` and `\>` are actually from Vim... maybe they're from both. Checking now...

Comment: But won't any word boundary be both the start of some word and the end of another word?  What is the distinction you're trying to handle?

Comment: @MarkReed, no, because a word boundary does match only the position directly before/after a word and NOT e.g. the whitespace before/after the word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing predefined. But what you can do is, to add a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to the word boundary, to check if it is the start or the end of the word.

`\<` would be then `\b(?=\w)`. This checks if after the word boundary a word character is following ==> start of the word. [See this as example on regexr](http://regexr.com?32rqg)

`\>` would be then `\b(?!\w)`. This checks if after the word boundary not a word character is following ==> end of the word

Comment: +1, but you should use `(?!\w)` instead of `(?=\W)` for the second case.

Comment: It's actually not just more clear - your solution would not have matched a word boundary at the end of the string.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky Uh, no. Just `(?!\w)`. Or `(?=\W|$)`, but that's awkward.